# How can I copy rich text (with html tags)?

Tags: ngx-clipboard

I am using a rich text editor (ckEditor) in my Angular 7 app. I now want an action button to copy the text entered in that editor to the clipboard, but via ngx-clipboard the html tags are literally in the text copied. How can I have the tags applied?

I don't know how to accomplish this. ngx-clipboard is third party. I have tried other examples making a custom directive, but got stuck on that.

This is how I call ngxClipboard:

```html
<button mat-button ngxClipboard [cbContent]="document._source.response" matTooltip="Copy response" matTooltipPosition="above"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material/24/000000/copy--v1.png"></button>
```

The content on the clipboard looks like this:

```html
<p>This is the copied text.&nbsp;It contains html tags</p>
```